# NodeJs: slow req.pipe

Tags: node.js, performance, express, stream, pipe

I've discovered that the server implementation of tus (https://tus.io) for nodejs (https://github.com/tus/tus-node-server) is really slow in comparison with the go implementation (https://github.com/tus/tusd).

Here you may find a comparison between the different implementations (running locally, same machine, same input)

nodejs:

```
[2019-01-31 16:22:45,578] INFO Uploading 52428800 bytes chunk from offset: 104857600
[2019-01-31 16:22:47,329] INFO Total bytes sent: 157286400 (kb/s: 29930)
```

go:

```
 [2019-01-31 16:26:31,894] INFO Uploading 52428800 bytes chunk from offset: 104857600
    [2019-01-31 16:26:32,348] INFO Total bytes sent: 209715200 (kb/s: 115639)
```

I've explored the tus-node-server codebase and then I've build a really simplified implementation of the server (i tried to reduce the possible overhead).

This is the code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

let offset = 0;
let len = Math.pow(2,30);

app.post('/files',(req,res) => {
    console.log("post received");
    res.set({
        'Location': 'http://localhost:8888/files/test',
        'Tus-Resumable': '1.0.0',
    });
    res.status(201).end();
});

app.options('/files',(req,res) => {
    console.log("options received");
    res.set({
        'Location': 'http://localhost:8888/files/test',
        'Tus-Resumable': '1.0.0',
        'Tus-Version': '1.0.0,0.2.2,0.2.1'
    });
    res.status(200).end();
});

app.head('/files/test',(req,res) => {
    console.log("options received");
    res.set({
        'Upload-Offset': offset,
        'Upload-Length': len
    });
    res.status(200).end();
});

app.patch('/files/test',(req, res) => {
    let localOffset = parseInt(req.get('Upload-Offset'), 10);
    // the file is pre-created
    const path = `./file.tmp`;
    const options = {
        flags: 'r+',
        start: localOffset
    };

    const stream = fs.createWriteStream(path, options);

    let new_offset = 0;
    req.on('data', (buffer) => {
        new_offset += buffer.length;
    });


    return req.pipe(stream).on('finish', () => {

        localOffset += new_offset;

        offset = localOffset;

        res.set({
            'Upload-Offset': offset,
            'Upload-Length': len
        });
        res.status(204).end();
    });


});

const host = 'localhost';
const port = 8888;
app.listen(port, host, (err, resp) => {
    if(err) {
        console.error(err);
        return
    }
    console.log('listening')
});
```

I think that the poor performance are due to the following code block:

```
const stream = fs.createWriteStream(path, options);
req.pipe(stream)
```

I've also check the file copy using a pipe and i got good performance (similar to go implementation)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const from = path.normalize(process.argv[2]);
const to = path.normalize(process.argv[3]);

const readOpts = {}; // {highWaterMark: Math.pow(2,16)};
const writeOpts ={}; // {highWaterMark: Math.pow(2,16)};

const startTs = Date.now();
const source = fs.createReadStream(from, readOpts);
const dest = fs.createWriteStream(to, writeOpts);
let offset = 0;

source.on('data', (buffer) => {
    offset += buffer.length;
});

dest.on('error', (e) => {
    console.log('[FileStore] write: Error', e);
});

source.pipe(dest).on('finish',() => {
    const endTs = Date.now();
    const kbs = (offset / (endTs - startTs)) / 1000;
    console.log("SPEED: ", kbs, offset);
});
```

so the bottleneck seems to be processing of the request an the piping.

Could you please help me to understand what happen and why is so slow compared with the go version

Comment: Hi, which version of node.js?

Comment: i tried with and v8 and v10.15.1 same results

Comment: Could you add also the tus client? I would like to try to find the problem 

Comment: Here you may find the client: http://paste.arn-fai.net/?2866606

Comment: if I run tusd with the following command line: "tusd -dir ./files -port 1081 -host localhost" I get similar performance (like node).  If i bind node on "all interfaces" i get better performance, I don't understand why it happens.

Comment: thank, I will try soon

Answer (score 4):

I think you have a `highWaterMark` problem here.

The difference between your test are due to:

- `req` has a highWaterMark of 16 kb
- `createReadStream` has a [highWaterMark of 64 kb](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options)

You can see the value adding:

```
console.log('readableHighWaterMark', req.readableHighWaterMark);
```

Instead, assuming your networking latency is negligible (because you are localhost), You
can try to create the `writeStream` with a bigger water mark:

```
const options = {
    flags: 'w',
    start: localOffset,
    highWaterMark: 1048576
};
const stream = fs.createWriteStream(path, options);
```

This should speed up the write but will cost more RAM.

Comment: upvoted! sorry if this is an unrelated comment but even after reading the docs I couldnt understand much beyond highwatermark is some sort of limit for the buffer to start pushing, what does increasing or decreasing the value of highwatermark actyally do

Comment: To make an example: the access to disk is infinity slower than access to RAM. If you have a small buffer you will need to read from disk more times, so you will be slower. Increasing the HighWaterMark you will increase the internal buffer so, with 1 disk access you will read more data. Read from http request is the same because you are reading from a socket that is a file descriptor.. a file at the end