# How to fix my stream/writing data closing really slow with NodeJS and promise-ftp

Tags: node.js, ftp, stream

I have to download a json file from a ftp server. Getting the file goes really fast but then the read/writing with stream closes really slow. The file is on my desktop almost instantly but its not closing.

I've tryed promise-ftp & just ftp. I updated my nodejs and node to the latest version so I tryed multiple version.

```js
const getFile = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('getting file.');
    ftp.connect(config)
      .then(function (serverMessage) {
        return ftp.get(remoteFile + '.json');
      }).then(function (stream) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          stream.once('close', resolve);
          stream.once('error', reject);
          stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${steamid}.json`));
        });
      }).then(async function () {
        console.log('done editing');
        await ftp.end();
        return resolve();
      }).catch(console.log);
  });
};
```

I expect this to download and close in like 1 second. It takes a solid 10 seconds to close the file but I can already see it instantly on my pc and read it. Its about 700kb for 1 file.

EDIT:
The FTP connection closes instantly but the stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${steamid}.json`)); takes 10 seconds to call the 'close' event eventhough the file looks fully downloaded instantly.

EDIT 2:
[There is a gap of 10 seconds after the 680 (thats the chunk.length) and then the Write stream is finished.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzyXN.png)

Its like it doesn't know there isn't more data coming.

**EDIT 3:**
So the files I download are around 700 bytes, its just 1 chunk maximum everytime. I fixed it by adding a "data" event on the readstream and after the 1 chunk I just destroy it. My whole download, edit, upload works in less than a second now. *This isn't probably an ideal solution*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the `promise-ftp` npm docs, if you want to immidiately close the FTP connection you should use the following method:

```
destroy(): Closes the connection to the server immediately. Returns a boolean indicating whether the connection was connected prior to the call to destroy().
```

In your case that would be:

```
const getFile = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('getting file.');
    ftp.connect(config)
      .then(function (serverMessage) {
        return ftp.get(remoteFile + '.json');
      }).then(function (stream) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          stream.once('close', resolve);
          stream.once('error', reject);
          stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${steamid}.json`));
        });
      }).then(async function () {
        console.log('done editing');
        await ftp.destroy();
        return resolve();
      }).catch(console.log);
  });
};
```

Comment: Well the problem is with the stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream());
Ending the ftp connection goes really fast but it takes long for the stream.pipe to call the 'close'

Comment: Ah, now I understand, the issue is then related solely to NodeJS streams. Have you tried to play around with the highWaterMark option? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54464491/nodejs-slow-req-pipe

Comment: The fact that you can see the file doesn't mean that it actually finished writing it, can you open it and visualise the content before the stream is closed?

Comment: Yes I can see the file, open it and see every information that has to be in it instantly. But then it takes another 9 seconds for the stream to actually call the 'close' event. Let me check the highWaterMark option.

Comment: Adding the highWaterMark didn't help. Its weird because the file is downloaded instantly. And I can see all the data in the json file.

Comment: So I just did some testing and added the 'data' event on the stream. It outputs only once then it stops for the 9 seconds and then it fires the 'close' event. So its not doing anything for 9 seconds.

Comment: How large are the files you have to download? Have you thought about using Buffers?

Comment: So the files I download are around 700 bytes, its just 1 chunk maximum everytime. I fixed it by adding a "data" event on the readstream and after the 1 chunk I just destroy it. My whole download, edit, upload works in less than a second now. This isn't probably an ideal solution. I haven't thought about buffers no. I'm new to it all :D

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely not an ideal solution, but as long as it works and it's not mission critical I guess it's fine :D. 
You could maybe improve it by converting the stream into a buffer using something like (https://github.com/stream-utils/stream-to). I'm not sure about the performance though.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but I have the same issue.
And finally I took up Marcel's idea. Just improved by looking at the size of the downloaded file.

```
var ftp = require('ftp');         // Client FTP
var fs  = require('fs');          // Gestion Fichier      

// Initialization
var distantFile     = 'example.dat';
var localFile           = distantFile;
var downloadedSize  = 0;
var fileSize        = 0;
        
var clientFtp = new ftp();
        
clientFtp.on('ready', function() {

    clientFtp.list(distantFile,function(errotList, listeElementDistant) {
            
            if(!errotList)
            {
                fileSize = listeElementDistant[0].size;

                clientFtp.get(distantFile, function(errotGet, stream) {

                    if(!errotGet)
                    {
                        stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(localFile));

                        stream.on('data',function(buffer){
                            downloadedSize += buffer.length;
                            console.log(downloadedSize+' '+fileSize+' '+(downloadedSize/fileSize*100).toFixed(1)+'%');


                            if(downloadedSize==fileSize)
                            {
                             clientFtp.end();
                             stream.destroy();
                             console.log('Download Complete');
                            }
                        });


                        stream.on('close', function(){
                            clientFtp.end();
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log('Error Get : '+errotGet);
                    }

                });
            }
            else
            {
                console.log('Error List : '+errotList);
            }

        });
});

clientFtp.connect(/*  You Must Define Options Connections */);
```